# expected dense_20 to have shape (None, 18827) but got array with shape (316491, 1)

Tags: keras

I am having some difficulty properly formatting my labels for keras (tensorflow backend). My model takes in an embedding (list of 128 numbers) as input and outputs one of 18827 distinct numbers (ranging from 1 to 20284) as such:

```
[0.0344733819366,...,0.153029859066] -> 11516
```

My training data consists of 316491 embedding-number pairings, so when I tried using `keras.utils.to_categorical(training_out, num_classes=20284)` to convert the number labels to one-hot vectors for `categorical_crossentropy`, I received a MemoryError. It seems that 
`sparse_categorical_crossentropy` would resolve this issue, since it looks like it only needs one number instead of a large vector as the label. However, I am not sure how to format my labels correctly for this. Currently my model is:

```
self.brain = Sequential()
self.brain.add(Dense(1000, input_dim=128))
self.brain.add(Dense(20284, activation='softmax'))
self.brain.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

When I try to fit the model I get the following errors, depending on how I format the labels:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_22 to have shape (None, 18827) but got array with shape (1, 316491)
```

or

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_20 to have shape (None, 18827) but got array with shape (316491, 1)
```

18827 is the number of distinct labels I have, but I don't think I specified that number anywhere in my code, so I don't know how or why that is the expected dimension for the labels, especially if each label isn't a vector.

I am unsure of whether I correctly understand sparse_categorical_crossentropy, and if I do, how to use it properly.

Comment: For me it works, if I just change loss='categorical_crossentropy' to loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy' without changing anything else. 
With this input:

X.shape
(316491, 128)

y.shape
(316491, 1)

Comment: Yes, that works, thank you! The 18827 issue disappeared when I opened a new console, too.

Answer (score 0):

Answer in the comment [expected dense_20 to have shape (None, 18827) but got array with shape (316491, 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48233971/expected-dense-20-to-have-shape-none-18827-but-got-array-with-shape-316491?noredirect=1#comment83452074_48233971)

From the Keras documentation https://keras.io/losses/

> Note: when using the categorical_crossentropy loss, your targets should be in categorical format (e.g. if you have 10 classes, the target for each sample should be a 10-dimensional vector that is all-zeros expect for a 1 at the index corresponding to the class of the sample). In order to convert integer targets into categorical targets, you can use the Keras utility to_categorical

In your case, you are not able to one-hot encode because of memory issues, so you need to use **sparse_categorical_crossentropy** instead.